# Make virt-sysprep not require sudo

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm currently running

```
virt-sysprep -v -x -d LOCALVM  --hostname LOCALVM --root-password password:123456
```

But it errores out saying

```
virt-sysprep: error: libguestfs error: guestfs_launch failed, see earlier 
error messages
```

But if I run this with `sudo` it works.  How do I set my user to not need sudo to be able to run virt-sysprep without it?

referencing the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/virt-sysprep.1.html)

> You do not need to run virt-sysprep as root. In fact we'd generally
>   recommend that you don't. The time you might want to run it as root is
>   when you need root in order to access the disk image, but even in this
>   case it would be better to change the permissions on the disk image to
>   be writable as the non-root user running virt-sysprep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to give ownership

`sudo chown -R user /usr/bin/virt-sysprep`

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Try `echo sudo -s >> /home(your username)/.bash_profile`. When starting up the terminal, you need to put in your password to use the terminal, however, you won't have to use `sudo` to execute `virt-sysprep`. Be careful with this, because with great power comes great responsability.
Method 2: Open a new terminal and type in `sudo visudo`. At the end of the file, type this in: `%yourusername% ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/virt-sysprep`. I'm guessing `virt-sysprep` is installed in `/usr/bin/virt-sysprep`. If you're not sure, type this in the terminal: `whereis virt-sysprep`. Replace the first directory with `/usr/bin/virt-sysprep`.

Comment: updated question in order to clarify

Comment: updated answer with second method.

Comment: your method works, but I got it to work with chown -R, see answer.  Thank you